# growth rate of n! versus $r^n$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, computational-mathematics

How do you show that $\lim_{n\to \infty} {n!\over {r^n}} $ approaches $\infty$?

the growth rate of $r^n$ is slower than $n!$, so the latter one is increasing faster, but how do you show the above question using analytical computation?

Comment: You can also use the Stirling approximation (not the complicated one, but the simple one, which can be derived from) $$\log(n!)=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\log(n)\approx \int_1^{n}\log(x)dx=[x\log(x)-x]_1^n=n*\log(n)-n+1$$. Exponentiate this expression and you have a good approximation for $n!$.

Comment: What do you mean by "analytical computation"? Alex Fish has posted an answer which was essentially what I was going to write - eventually $n\gt 2r$ and each term is more than twice the previous one. Since the terms are positive, they are unbounded. What more or different do you want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Denote $A=\{n\in \mathbb{N}\mid \frac{n}{r}\geq 2\}$. $A$ is a set of integers bounded from below thus it has a minimum. Let $n_0=min_n\{n\in A\}$. Now we have $\frac{n!}{r^n}\geq \frac{n_0!}{r^{n_0}}2^{n-n_0}$. The inequality applies for the limits: $lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{n!}{r^n}\geq lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{n_0!}{r^{n_0}}2^{n-n_0}=\frac{n_0!}{(2r)^{n_0}}lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}2^{n}=\infty$.

Comment: you are comparing the original expression to something that is bigger than the original one and that goes to infinity, how does that show that the original problem go to infinity? Just like you wrote in the last line, it still less than or equal to infinity, does that still suffice?

Comment: Sorry, the inequality is incorrect. Obviously it is greater or equal. *EDITED*

Answer (score 0):

Let $f(n)=r^n/n!$ As soon as $n\geq2 r$ we have $f(n+1)=r^{n+1}/(n+1)!=(r/(n+1))r^n/n!=(r/(n+1)f(n)<(1/2)f(n)$ so every time we increase n by 1, the value of $f(n)$ drops by more than half. E.g. for $n\geq 2 r$ we also have $n+1>2 r$ and $n+2> 2r$, so $f(n+3)<f(n+2)/2<f(n+1)/4<f(n)/8.$